# mysql compute no of leaves thru months

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
Name    duration    date_leave_from date_leave_to
John    1           2015-03-01      2015-03-01
Doe     .5          2015-03-02      2015-03-02
John    .5          2015-03-02      2015-03-02
Doe     1           2015-01-03      2015-01-03
Doe     1           2015-02-04      2015-02-04
```

I would like to get the data in the following format:

```
Name      ||  Jan     ||   Feb    ||  March     ||  April .. to DEC
John      ||  1       ||   0      ||  1.5       ||  0  
Doe       ||  0       ||   1      ||  .5        ||  0
```

Comment: What if the from->to range spans across a new month?

Comment: supposed to be it should be Jan to december I did not include it to the column

Comment: seems right

select `requester`,
       sum(case when month(date_leave_from) = 1 then duration else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when month(date_leave_from) = 2 then duration else 0 end) as feb,
       sum(case when month(date_leave_from) = 3 then duration else 0 end) as mar,
       sum(case when month(date_leave_from) = 4 then duration else 0 end) as apr       
from tbl_hr_leave_form
group by `requester`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT name,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '1' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Jan,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '2' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Feb,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '3' THEN duration else 0 END) AS March,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '4' THEN duration else 0 END) AS April,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '5' THEN duration else 0 END) AS May,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '6' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Jun,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '7' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Jul,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '8' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Aug,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '9' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Sep,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '10' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Oct,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '11' THEN duration else 0 END) AS Nov,
   SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(from_date) = '12' THEN duration else 0 END) AS   December
FROM test
GROUP BY name
```

This is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25160/3)